# How to change nested Model using entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have a "nested" Entity Framework model structure. Here are my models:

```
class Parent
{
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    virtual ICollection<Child> children {get;set;}
}

class Child
{
    public int ChildId {get;set;}
    public Parent Parent  {get;set;}
    virtual ICollection<Account> accounts {get;set;}
}

class Account
{
    public int AccountId {get;set;}
    public Child Child  {get;set;}
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
}

class DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> parents {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Child> children {get;set;}
    public DbSet<Account> accounts {get;set;}
}
```

How do I change the Account.SomeProperty for all Accounts belonging to a certain Parent with minimal DB queries?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var db = new DbContext();
var accounts = db.accounts.Where(a => a.Child.Parent.ParentId == parentId);
foreach (var account in accounts)
{
    account.SomeProperty = ...;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

It will generate just one query (with necessary joins) to retrieve *"all Accounts belonging to a certain Parent"*. How many update statements will be generated is out of your control.